# How can I do "opt-in" interfaces with a proxy class in C++?

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism

I have 5 classes named `A B C D E` and 2 interfaces `I1 I2`. Using multiple inheritance, I might inherit abstract classes to implement interfaces:

`class A : public I1, I2 {};`

---

Now, I want to add more interfaces `I3 I4 I5`.

Having to modify all 5 class definitions is tedious and violates `Don't Repeat Yourself` as a programming principle.

**How might I implement an interface proxy class to encapsulate the polymorphic side of the interface instead of multiple inheritance of abstract base classes?**

In other words, I want to have a class be cast to an interface class without using inheritance. Would a type operator overload be suitable here? Or, perhaps using a constructor per class would be good? **The goal is to minimize repetition of code.**

Comment: Given that you have to write the code to implement the new interfaces I don't see what you have to gain by avoiding adding the command that inherits the interface. Maybe you could provide a more concrete example of what you want to do and what you expect to gain?

Comment: If you don't want to repeat things like `public I1, public I2, public I3`, create an interface that inherits from I1,I2,I3, and inherit from that.

Comment: @n.m: what if a new interface gets added `public I4` to the original composite interface? OP does not want to inherit from multiple interface yet achieve their functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this problem as follows:

- Classes A, B, C,... are type of documents say, JPG, DOC, RTF, XML, PDF,...
- Interfaces I1, I2, I3,... as functionalities common to documents say, IPrint, ISaveToFile, ICompress.

So, every document A, B, C,... needs to implement these inferfaces in order to provide these functionalities.

If I have described your requirement correctly then, you can use [Design Pattern : Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Also, I can go in detail if this fits your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Change you classes declarations slightly to add one more level of indirection?

```
class A: public I;
class B: public I;
class C: public I;
struct I: I1, I2 /* we will add I3, I4 and I5 tomorrow */
```

Comment: What if tomorrow a new `interface I4` gets added and has a `pure virtual function`? So definitely `struct I` is not going to implement this `pure virtual function`. So `classes A, B and C` are forced to implement the functionality exposed by new `interface I4`. So in any case `classes A, B, C` needs modification and this is what OP is trying to eliminate when a new `inteface` gets added to system.

Comment: Mmmm, sorry I don't quite follow. If you inherit an abstract class from a concrete class, you have to implement all the former's pure virtual methods. If a set of classes inherit the same abstract class each, you have to add methods implementations for each of them. If they inherit that abstract class indirectly through a single ancestor, you can define a default implementation in that ancestor, and then a custom implementation in one of derived classes, if you need one. Or what is your point?

Comment: Well, if the single ancestor provides a default implementation then this point makes sense. But then again why would any one use concrete `classes A, B, C` if all the required functionalities are available via single ancestor. So **I guess** all the existing and new interfaces are the functionalities common to and which `classes A, B, C` needs to implement.

Comment: Are you asking why would anyone use concrete classes? Sorry I don't quite follow.

Comment: See, what i understood from OP requirement is that the concrete classes should not be changed at code level even when a new Interface gets added to system. Yet the concrete classes should be able to provide the required functionalities which came with new Interface.

Comment: Making a class implement a new interface is changing it anyway, so that requirement cannot be fulfilled. The implementation can be hidden under the intermediate ancestor, then the most derived classes won't be changed, but if you need a specific method for a particular class you'll have to define that specific override anyway.

Comment: That's were Visitor Design Pattern may help. It creates a framework upfront, so that you can add new functionalities (in the form of visitor object) outside of concrete classes and then pass the visitor object in concrete classes. Then concrete classes pass their identity in visitor object thereby fulfilling the requirement of implementing new functionalities. It may sound cryptic but once you go through the pattern, things become clear.

Comment: Yes, I suppose Visiting might be ideologically true when an interface actually does not declare any useful functionality but rather is something of a meta: `class MyWebService also extends ReffererStats` (I wonder if there is a programming language out there with `also` as a keyword :) ). But to implement class's primary functionality in such a fashion would be wrong IMO. That should have done something with private members exposure and other encaps. violation.

Comment: For example say, `Printing(),Compress()` are generic requirements which needs to be provided by each of different document types. Now these document will have their own primary way of handling things which if required to change then they should be made internally in the concrete classes itself. Now, if a new generic requirement comes into picture say 'DisplayOnScreen()' then `DisplayOnScreen()` needs to be implemented by all concrete classes then this can be done externally.

Comment: Visitor helps you in extending generic requirements which are required to be implemented by all the concrete classes without changing themself.